# Bootstrap now being found?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, I'm losing it here. This should be super simple but I'm just about at my whits end trying to figure out why Bootstrap is not working.

I'm going to help add Bootstrap to a club's existing WebFrom site. I Added Bootstrap through NugGet and when that didn't work I downloaded the files off of Bootstrap's site and added them manually. I dragged and dropped the files into their place so that it would make the correct links.

When I run this locally I get no CSS or bootstrap styling at all. I don't see any errors in the browser's console either.

Hopefully someone can see something I'm not seeing.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SiteBS.master.cs" Inherits="NorthTexasCamaroClub.SiteBS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="header-title">
                </span>

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>Club Info</li>
                    <li>Events</li>
                    <li>Event Photos</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    </form>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the Network tab on the browser inspector? I expect it to be an 404 request.

Comment: Is your bootstrap.css file in a subfolder called "Content" with an uppercase C (for some reason)? And is it called "bootstrap.css" and not "bootstrap.min.css"?

Comment: Or `<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />`.

Comment: In  visual studio, check the properties of bootstrap's files. They should be marked as "content" against "Build action". That will ensure that those files are taken up as part of the build process when you publish the web application.

Comment: @Toan...the network tab has a status of 200 for the .aspx page, jQuery file, and Bootstrap file.

Comment: @FluffyKittin...yes, the bootstrap.css files are in a folder called "Content". I dragged and dropped the files onto the masterpage just to make sure they were correctly spelled and formed. The Content folder is the default created folder when you add Bootstrap through NuGet.

Comment: @wazz...I did try the "/" in front of the of the Content folder without any luck. I even tried adding bootstrap.css to the root of the site and changed the href to point to it without any luck.

Comment: @Nisarg...I checked the properties on the bootstrap file and the jQuery file and then are all set to "content".

Comment: Does any one know if there is a way to look in the Dev Tools of Chrome and see if it shows that the Bootstrap and jQuery files were loaded correctly?

Comment: "*Does any one know if there is a way to look in the Dev Tools of Chrome and see if it shows that the Bootstrap and jQuery files were loaded correctly?*" Just view the source and click on them :) If the file is there, it will open. Did you check that the css file isn't called bootstrap.min.css (because you are using the minified js file), and that the path to the folder is correct - i.e. it is a sub folder in the location your html page is?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on clicking the files from View Source. That worked for all three files. They opened right up. I have both the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css in the folder. I initially tried the min version but went to the full version when that didn't seem to work. The siteBS.master file is in the root of the site and the Bootstrap files are in the subfolder called Content right off of the root.

Comment: So now I'm even more stumped. I was able to view all three files from the View Source yet it still doesn't work This shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: Also, though this shouldn't make that much of a difference, I did check the Project Properties and it's set to .Net v4.5.